# I am having trouble retrieving my react project in the browser

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react and I just closed my work and I am now trying to get it back in the browser through the terminal using npm start/ npx start but to no avail, kindly how do I get it back running in the browser that I may proceed with my work.

Comment: You should be able to access your project on ```http://localhost:3000``` if you're using ```create-react-app```

Comment: Do you see any messages in terminal after you execute the `npm start` command?

Answer (score 1):

Kill anything else running on port 3000.

```
kill $(sudo lsof -t -i:3000)
```

Then

```
npm start
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Cmd to kill running port `3000`: `fuser -n tcp -k 3000`

#### Then run the project: `npm start`